# Openstack nova terminating guest vms with oom_kill

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I am running an openstack Victoria with Kolla ansible deployment , all components are containerised .

The compute node is (oom_kill) killing guest when the memory is max out , is there a way to avoid it like in other hypervisors it works fine without this issue .
I am using Centos 8.3 . Please let me know if there is a way to avoid this .

Errors :

```
**Feb 27 12:18:15 server1 kernel: neutron-openvsw invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x6200ca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Feb 27 12:18:15 server1 kernel: oom_kill_process.cold.28+0xb/0x10
Feb 27 12:18:15 server1 kernel: [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
Feb 27 12:18:15 server1 kernel: oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=395bde13c7e0570ef36df008bc028d8701fd76c1b56e2a56afaf254fd53d0043,mems_allowed=0-1,global_oom,task_memcg=/machine/qemu-33-instance-000000dc.libvirt-qemu,task=qemu-kvm,pid=2301214,uid=42436
Feb 27 12:18:17 server1 kernel: oom_reaper: reaped process 2301214 (qemu-kvm), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:516kB, shmem-rss:0kB**
```

sar memory utilisation

```
==================================
10:10:05 AM kbmemfree   kbavail kbmemused  %memused kbbuffers  kbcached  kbcommit   %commit  kbactive   kbinact   kbdirty
12:00:05 PM    877228         0 393690660     99.78         0    500284 2254123104    542.46 374227828  12705256         0
12:10:04 PM    866416         0 393701472     99.78         0    501844 2254259520    542.49 374233440  12704360         0
12:20:04 PM 301182096 300028052  93385792     23.67         0    705140 1938778932    466.57  83794716   5028804         8
12:30:04 PM 301085624 299970968  93482264     23.69         0    779220 1939000988
```

Comment: This sounds like [this thread](http://lists.openstack.org/pipermail/openstack-discuss/2022-February/027350.html) in the openstack-discuss mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own questioun as I found a resolution .

The oom kills were happening even when free stats were looking good like on a 256G RAM only 140G was used and still around 100G shows up as free .

[root@serverxx ~]# free -g
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            251         140         108           0           2         108
Swap:            19           6          13

oom kills were triggered by high %commit in the sar stats where the kernel starts targetting instances with high memory footprint to free up .

To avoid oom kills for the guest instances with higher memory footprints , I set the following .
vm.oom_kill_allocating_task=1

When I did a sar -r the %commit was way higher than the system can allocate and I figured from ps that it was a cinder-backup container that was created by default from kolla-ansible deployments but was not configured .

Cinder backup service stats that I didn't configure and it was just running , it turned out that the unconfigured container was taking up all the memory overtime as seen from the output of ps command in the vsz .

ps -eo args,comm,pid,ppid,rss,vsz --sort vsz column

**VSZ is extremely high**

COMMAND                     COMMAND             PID    PPID   RSS    VSZ
/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm -name qemu-kvm        1916998   47324 8094744 13747664
/var/lib/kolla/venv/bin/pyt cinder-backup     43689   43544 170999912 **870274784**

Sar stats for % commit coming back to normal after the backup container was stopped and now everything is back to normal . %commit highlighted from **1083.46 to 14.21** after the changes .

02:00:37 PM kbmemfree   kbavail kbmemused  %memused kbbuffers  kbcached  kbcommit   %commit  kbactive   kbinact   kbdirty
03:00:37 PM  48843576  49998184  82890508     62.92      9576   5949348 1427280428   **1083.46**  75646888   2797388       324
03:10:37 PM  48829248  49991284  82904836     62.93      9576   5956544 1427343664   **1083.50**  75653556   2804592       116
03:20:22 PM 120198612 121445516  11535472      8.76      9576   6042892  18733688     **14.22**   4887688   2854704        80
03:30:37 PM 120189464 121444176  11544620      8.76      9576   6050200  18725820     **14.21**   4887752   2862248        88